# React Native - pod install issue "cannot load such file.......node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods"

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios, pod-install

when I have a react native project....and when I run `pod install` it gives me the following error

```
Invalid `Podfile` file: cannot load such file -- /myPath/node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods
```

Here is my podfile

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'xs' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

  target 'xsTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  use_flipper!
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
end

target 'xs-tvOS' do
  # Pods for xs-tvOS

  target 'xs-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end
```

Ive checked and there is no file called `react_native_pods` in location `myPath/node_modules/react-native/scripts/`.
Im wondering if its something to do with `npm install` is not generating correct files.....however I upgraded node to most recent version and then ran `npm install`

Comment: Try to remove the package lock json file and npm install again. if issue still exist update CocoaPods

Comment: This didnt work - see my answer below

Answer (score 52):

I ran `npm audit fix` and it added `react_native_pods` file and `pod install` then worked

Comment: Thanks, this helped identify some errors in the `package-lock.json` file. I had to run `npm install` to fix it, after which `pod install` worked.

Comment: Wow amazing! Anyone knows why this works?

Comment: @Jarrett you run npm install first, because you need to install node specific things first, after that you can run pod install, and according to [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-audit) npm audit fix runs npm install under the hood

Comment: `react-native-pod` (not pods)

Answer (score 16):

Run npm audit fix  ==> cd ios ==> pod install

Comment: Wow amazing! Anyone knows why this works?

Comment: But this is changing the package.json which is not intended as it effects other parts of the code

Comment: @ravi I don't think this is affecting anything, bc what we are doing here is updating the pod files, our pod files were lagging on the update. so no need to worry.

Answer (score 16):

If `npm audit fix` is not working for you then try below solution.

```
- sudo gem install cocoapods
- npm i
- cd ios
- pod install
```

Comment: Updating cocoapods with `sudo gem install cocoapods` really helped. Thanks Man

Answer (score 13):

It can also be that you just forgot to run `yarn` / `npm` before running `pod install`.

Comment: This is what I was missing

Answer (score 4):

I have meet the same error, solved by upgrade the version of React Native from 0.62 to 0.63, it works for me
Because of the file react_native_pods does't exists in the folder scripts when the version is 0.62, It appears when I upgraded the version of RN to 0.63, after npm install , It works when pod install, hope it would help other who encounter the same error

Answer (score 4):

I just did  `npm install` before running `pod install` and it solved for me.

Comment: Or just do `yarn install` and then pod install

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you've installed your npm dependencies.

Run following command and then install pods.

1. To install npm packages:

> ```
> yarn install
> ```

2. And then, remove old pod cache:

> ```
> cd ios && pod deintegrate && rm -rf Podfile.lock
> ```

3. To update pods and start ios:

> ```
> pod install --repo-update && cd .. && react-native run-ios
> ```

Comment: I forgot to install node_modules first. (≧︿≦)! -(－‸ლ)-

Answer (score 3):

In my case Ive deleted yarn.lock, podfile.lock and it worked fine after yarn and pod install again

Answer (score 1):

in order to fix this: what i did is:

1. react-native upgrade: It mainly upgrades react-native version, which will also upgrade some of your ios files such as Podfile amongst other things.

Try if this works for you or not. You can also create a latest react native project and compare your files/directories using "Beyond compare", also you need to rename some lines in your files.

Also read the comments in files for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

This wroked for me:

```
cd ios
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Via this [link](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/652822).

Answer (score 1):

just install,

```
@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios
```

in package.json

then `yarn install` in your root and `cd ios` and also `arch -x86_64 pod install`

Answer (score 1):

I had this error in 2022 and this was the most relevant search result and didn't fix it.. so in case anyone else out there is running into this, I fought this for days and finally fixed it by:

Creating a brand new directory by: expo init new-project and then copy over your .js files, screens, and assets etc. Do this by hand, don't copy any of your lock files or node-modules or anything else. Just the files that you created/touched yourself. Then expo start. Load the project on your mobile / simulator and when it fails with a module requirement missing add it individually. Repeat this start-error-add until the build succeeds. This was the only way I found to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I installed `cocoapods` from `brew` and `gem`

Based on the latest react-native documents, you will need to install it from `gem`

Do the following steps:

1. `sudo brew uninstall cocoapods` to remove cocoapods install via `brew`
2. `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods` to remove cocoapods installed via `gem`

Finally

3. `sudo gem install cocoapods` to install the latest version via `gem`

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me on mac after installing MacOs 14.0 Sonoma. I'm not entirely sure what the issue was. The files that were being relatively required by either

1. `require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'`

or

2.

```
Resolve react_native_pods.rb with node to allow for hoisting
require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
  'require.resolve(
    "react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb",
    {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
  )', __dir__]).strip
```

Existed and i could expect them but cocoapods could either not make sense of them or not locate them.

In the end i had to completely remove `rvm` with `rvm implode` and rvm uninstall. Reinstall it cleanly and use a Ruby version compatible with the one listed in my `Gemfile` `ruby ">= 2.6.10"`

I chose to use `2.7.8` as it's the highest `2.x.y` version, at present.

After that i had to reinstall the following gems

- activeSupport 7.0.8
- bundler
- cocoapods

I went to the root of the react-native project and did `bundle install`

Then went into `ios` and ran pod install.

This was all on a freshly created react-native project
`npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject`

```
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.5",
```

And everything seemed to be working fine. My theory is that after updating MacOs. It replaced some of my rvm path binaries with ones from the default installation breaking things. Or, my ruby version was just wrong/confused on `3.x` and i needed a fresh start on the compatible `2.x.y` version.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this error by using the standard system terminal instead of the integrated VSCode terminal

Comment: Thanks - I was trying to reuse a JavaScript Debug Console and hit this. Using a zsh console instead worked.

Answer (score 0):

Yarn
cd ios
pod install

Works for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

verify that you have a node_modules folder, I was missing that

Answer (score -1):

Go and add react-native.pods.rb file inside of Node_Module->React-Native->Scripts->(add here)